# Missing manifest tag OpenIDE-Module

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

In a newly generated project I started getting this error when trying to compile the branding module:

> --- nbm-maven-plugin:4.1:nbm (default-nbm) @ QualityTrends-branding --- Copying module JAR to /home/javier/Desktop/QualityTrends/branding/target/nbm/netbeans/qualitytrends/modules
>   Cannot generate config file.

Later this is further expanded:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:nbm-maven-plugin:4.1:nbm
>   (default-nbm) on project QualityTrends-branding: Missing manifest tag
>   OpenIDE-Module;
>   /home/javier/Desktop/QualityTrends/branding/target/nbm/netbeans/qualitytrends/modules/net-sourceforge-javydreamercsw-QualityTrends-branding.jar
>   is not a module -> [Help 1]

Inspecting the module's manifest file shows that entry missing, but it's missing as well in all other modules, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

This are the file's contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
OpenIDE-Module-Localizing-Bundle: net/sourceforge/javydreamercsw/quality/trends/branding/Bundle.properties
AutoUpdate-Essential-Module: true
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you miss maven-jar-plugin in your pom.xml.
Check your pom and add the following section if missed in `<plugins>` section.

```
<plugin> <!-- required since nbm-plugin 3.0-->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <useDefaultManifestFile>true</useDefaultManifestFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Compare your pom file with: http://www.mojohaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/

Comment: That got me through the error. Still seems like a bug since it was created by the IDE.

Answer (score 13):

If using a the maven-jar-plugin that is recent (3.0.0 or higher), Usual Java's answer will no longer work because the useDefaultManifestFile parameter was removed as per this [jira task](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-210).

The following will replicate what "useDefaultManifestFile=true" was doing:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```